# Which of these is the correct form?

Tags: verbs, american-english

```
The equipment ....... delivered tomorrow afternoon.
```

**A)** will been **B)** will be

---

And I appreciate it if you explain the differences between the two of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean: **A)** will have been **B)** will be

In this case the correct answer is **B**.

"Will have been" is used when the instance occurs before a certain date in the future.

For example: "By 2050, our cars **will have been** replaced with spaceships."

"Will be" is used when the instance occurs at an exact date in the future.

For example: "Our cars **will be** replaced with spaceships tomorrow."

**The equipment will be delivered tomorrow afternoon.**

If you want to use the other answer, you would write:

**The equipment will have been delivered by tomorrow afternoon.**

Comment: Just to clarify: the combination _will been_ does not exist in English.